# Move rooftop air conditioner condenser: Drill through tar-like blanket?

Tags: air-conditioning, roof

On a single story flat roof private home I need to move a rooftop air conditioning condenser 20 cm for a solar panel install. Fortunately the sloppy original install left enough electrical cable and refrigerant hose dangling whereas I do not need to concern myself with them. All I need to do is remove the four bolts in the roof, remount in the new location, and seal the original holes.

The house was constructed in 2017. The roof is concrete with a tar-like blanket on top. I do not know how thick the blanket or roof are.

**Is it enough to simply drill through the tar-like blanket, into the concrete, and place anchors there?**

Comment: do you happen to know the thickness of the roof concrete and the weight of the AC

Comment: @knowitall I do not know the thickness of the roof concrete, but this is a recent (2017) construction. The AC unit is a one horsepower single-room unit, but I could not find online what are typical weights for that type of unit. My guess from having carried on once would be on the order of 50 kilograms. If I find the exact weight I'll post it. Thank you.

Comment: Far too many questions in one.

Comment: @FreeMan I've reasked each question individually. Thank you.

Comment: Vote retracted. Thank _you_!

Comment: Why the downvote? How could I improve the question? I think that I included all relevant information, and I addressed the issue that FreeMan brought up.

Comment: *rooftop air conditioning radiator* - I hope you mean a *condenser*... that's on a roof. A *roof-top* unit goes into the roof through a *curb*; those don't 'move' w/o re-doing the curb (and the duct work). Condensers generally just sit on a pad (if even); I wouldn't be penetrating the roof if I didn't have to. And there *should* be enough line to move it so you can fix the roof regularly.

Comment: @Mazura Thank you, yes, the unit on the roof _condenses_ the refrigerant and _radiates_ the heat away. I will update the question with the proper English terminology, thank you very much.

Comment: Frame challenge: if the situation (physical dimensions etc.) allows it (and the aesthetics won't bother you) you could also leave the original bolts and install a bracket, onto the bolts, that holds the AC 20cm away.
Advantages: No additional roof penetration, no risk of drilling into a pipe or cable
Detriments: Somehow sloppy

Comment: @Martin Thank you, that might actually be a viable solution. I might add a single additional bolt at the end for stability, but I actually do like this idea.

Answer (score 2):

Remove one of the screws and you'll have a good idea of the depth and size of the new holes and maybe the type of anchors used.. Take the screw to your home store and pick out the appropriate anchors for that screw. I prefer lag bolts and lag shields. To fill in the old holes pick up some wet or dry roof patch, also available at your home store. 20 cm  is a good distance between holes. Whether you upgrade your roof with an additional blanket would be opinion based and would depend on the condition of your roof and the age.

If you don't have the tools to drill the holes, you might be able to get the solar panel installers to do it.

Comment: Terrific, thank you. You're 100% correct, with one old bolt in hand the home store should know what I need. I do have a proper drill and bits.